# Custom 400 with message being overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have some custom error messages I want to display to the user. So when they say enter a bad username/password combo I might do this in my code:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
return Json("Invalid username or password");
```

This works fine on my local machine. I've been deploying to a web host and these messages are being overwritten by the server so that they all come out as:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

The server is obviously trying to protect me from revealing sensitive information about what went wrong but I actually do want this error to go through and be seen by the user (well really, parsed by my code and then displayed).

I assume there's something in web.config I can do to make this work but everything I've tried thus far hasn't work. Any ideas?

Relevant section of web.config as I have it now:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    </httpErrors>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being removing the < httpErrors > element from web.config entirely. Even setting it to its default options as seen here http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors didn't work so I'm a bit perplexed why removing it works.

```
<system.webServer>
    **Remove <httpErrors> !**
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

By the default, some HTTP status codes are obscured by IIS and replaced by it. However, it can be configured by using this line:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
```

This will allow you to pass your custom message in a response and to read it on the client side when AJAX call is done.

Comment: I too thought it would be something like that, particularly the "PassThrough" part. Anyway, I tried it the exact way you have in your answer and I still get the simple one liner message. :\

Comment: Worked for me. Careful not to get it confused with the "<customErrors>" of the "<system.web>".

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle each Http error code you need to add the specific mapping on the web.config file

```
 <customErrors mode="On/RemoteOnly" >
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="My400View" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="My404iew" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="My500View" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Well, this an AJAX call, so no view. I want to display a text message informing the user that their input was not accepted. Would your suggestion work for that?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can use the `statusCode` property (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: And if I have multiple error messages? There is a descriptive error message in the response, I can see that locally. Problem is there's something in my hosted server preventing that from being delivered.