# IIS 7 Bad Request (ERROR 400) when querystring has invalid date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, iis

As strange as this may sound, I've been getting a Bad Request (error 400) response from IIS whenever I post a form that has an invalid date in a datetime field, as if IIS knows it's supposed to be a datetime value and is validating it somehow.

**UPDATE (added more information)**

- It's an ASP.NET / MVC 4.0 website.
- All datetime fields in the model are declared as string (for other
  reasons), so I don't think it's  model validation.
- This behavior only occurs in one of the servers, all other machines (developer and servers) are ok.

**UPDATE 2 (added more information)**

- It's seems to be a proxy related issue. When accessing the site locally, it works. When accessing it from another computer, returns bad request.

**UPDATE 3 (add more information)**

- Ruled out the "proxy hypothesis". I enabled request tracing in IIS, this was logged:

**ModuleName:** ManagedPipelineHandler
**Notification:** 128
**HttpStatus:** 400
**HttpReason:** Bad Request
**HttpSubStatus:** 0
**ErrorCode:** 0
**Notification:** EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
**ErrorCode:** A operação foi concluída com êxito. (0x0)

I have two posts:

`btnProcessarAutuacao=Processar&IdAutuacao=5000038&DataLimiteIdentificacaoCondutor=31%2F12%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&DscMensagemErro=Numero+do+auto+de+Infra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+A151515+para+o+Orgao+autuador+100107+j%C3%A1+foi+digitalizado&Placa=GVQ3641&AIT=A151515&CodInfracao=7471&DscInfracao=EXC.VELOC.ALEM+50%25+MAX++++++++&CodOrgaoAutuador=100107&DscOrgaoAutuador=GOVERNO+DO+DISTRITO+FEDERAL&DataEmissao=09%2F01%2F2014&DataInfracao=31%2F12%2F2013&HoraAutuacao=10%3A10%3A00&CodMunicipio=643&DscMunicipio=643&Local1=p_local145&Local2=p_local245&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

2)
`btnProcessarAutuacao=Processar&IdAutuacao=5000038&DataLimiteIdentificacaoCondutor=31%2F12%2F2013+00%3A00%3A00&DscMensagemErro=Numero+do+auto+de+Infra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+A151515+para+o+Orgao+autuador+100107+j%C3%A1+foi+digitalizado&Placa=GVQ3641&AIT=A151515&CodInfracao=7471&DscInfracao=EXC.VELOC.ALEM+50%25+MAX++++++++&CodOrgaoAutuador=100107&DscOrgaoAutuador=GOVERNO+DO+DISTRITO+FEDERAL&DataEmissao=31%2F02%2F2014&DataInfracao=31%2F12%2F2013&HoraAutuacao=10%3A10%3A00&CodMunicipio=643&DscMunicipio=643&Local1=p_local145&Local2=p_local245&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

The second post sends and invalid date (02/31/2014) for the "DataEmissao" parameter and IIS responds with error 400 (Bad Request). The first post has a valid date for the same parameter, IIS responds with OK (200).

That's the only difference I could find in these requests.

Any clues to what is happening?

Comment: Do you know what the application runtime is (e.g. ASP.NET?). I'm assuming there must be one, as you have tagged this as `c#`.

Comment: You tagged this as MVC, so my first thought is that you have a DateTime field in your model binding.  If you may not be getting a valid date, try changing it to a Nullable DateTime

Comment: @MarkPeters, you're right, it's MVC 4.0. All my datetime fields in the model are strings (for other reasons) and I do my own validation. This problem is only happening in one of the servers, all other machines (developer and server) are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it figured out.

I'm doing custom server-side validation, and whenever some field has an invalid value, I set the response code to 400 (Bad Request) and return a custom error message.

When testing locally, my custom error message goes through. When testing remotely, my custom message is replace with a default IIS error page.

All I had to do was add this to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

So that my custom response text goes without being replaced by the IIS default message.

Got the answer from here: [Custom 400 with message being overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581034/custom-400-with-message-being-overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strange at all :)

IIS doesn't know what the data-type of the query string parameter is supposed to be, but the application framework does. For example, if this is an ASP.NET web-page, then the ASP.NET runtime could be generating the 400, or, alternatively, a programmer could have implemented a check on the type and manually set the return code to 400.

Without more details (and some code!) it's impossible to say precisely where the 400 is being generated, but it will be along these lines...

Comment: Sorry, I should've given more information. It's ASP.NET with MVC 4.0. There is a model, but all datetime fields are string (for other reasons). This problem is only happening in one of the servers, all other machines (developers and servers) are ok.